# Windows Phone Only Saving One Character of String

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to write a string of text to a file in Windows Phone 8.1 using the following code:

```
public async Task WriteDataToFileAsync(String fileName, String content)
{
    Byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);

    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        await s.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

However, it is only writing the first character of whatever text I tell it to write. What am I doing wrong!?

EDIT: Here is how I read it:

```
public async Task<String> ReadFileContentsAsync(String fileName)
{
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    try
    {
        var file = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(fileName);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the size of the resulting file, in bytes?

Comment: Are you writing 8 characters? (Hopefully, yes.) How are you reading the file?

Comment: See my updated question. No, it doesn't matter how many characters I write. (Although, incidentally, I have normally been writing eight).

Comment: How are you checking that the string you read has only one character?

Comment: I am doing `textbox.Text = await ReadFileContentsAsync("file.txt");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be an encoding issue. When you read the file, try specifying the same encoding you used to write the file:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Unicode))
```

**Explanation:** The file is written as Unicode but read as UTF-8 (because there is no byte order mark). The extra NUL characters cause the text box to truncate the text after the first character.